# Apex unit test for new record fields

Tags: apex, unit-test

I can't seem to get code coverage on the following lines of code. Probably overlooking something but could use extra pair of eyes.

```
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.Liability__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_Liability_Limits__c;
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.PIP_Limits__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_PIP_Limits__c;
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.PIP_Deductible__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_PIP_Deductible__c;
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.UIM_Limits__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_UIM_Limits__c;
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.UM_Limits__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_UM_Limits__c;            
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_Liability_Limit__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_Liability_Limit__c;
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_PIP_Limit__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_PIP_Limit__c;
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_PIP_Deductible__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_PIP_Deductible__c;
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_UIM_Limit__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_UIM_Limit__c;
        this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_UM_Limit__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_UM_Limit__c;
```

You'll find the utility class, controller and unit test code below.

Utility Class:

```
       //build the Auto Sample object
public static Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c getAuto_Audit_Sample_Policy(Id AccId) {
        Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c samplePolicy = new Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c();
        samplePolicy.Audit__c = AccId;
        samplePolicy.Policy_Number__c = 'sampleTest';
        samplePolicy.Insured_ZipCode__c = '99999';        
        samplePolicy.Default_Liability_Limits__c = 'Other';
        samplePolicy.Default_PIP_Limits__c = 'Other';
        samplePolicy.Default_PIP_Deductible__c = 'Other';
        samplePolicy.Default_UIM_Limits__c = 'Other';
        samplePolicy.Default_UM_Limits__c = 'Other';
        samplePolicy.Other_Liability_Limit__c = '77777';
        samplePolicy.Other_PIP_Limit__c = '77777';
        samplePolicy.Other_PIP_Deductible__c = '77777';
        samplePolicy.Other_UIM_Limit__c = '77777';
        samplePolicy.Other_UM_Limit__c = '77777'; 

        return samplePolicy;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class AuditAutoVehicleSampleController {
    //Protected Members
    private final ApexPages.StandardController stdController;  
    private final string auditIdPrefix;

    //Properties
    public boolean IsNew {get;set;}

    public Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c AuditAutoPolicySample {get;set;}
    public Audit__c Audit {get;set;}
    public Auto_Vehicle__c AuditAutoVehicle {get;set;}
    String sampleId;

    //Constructors
    public AuditAutoVehicleSampleController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        try {
            stdController = controller;

            //Init Properties
            this.AuditAutoVehicle = (Auto_Vehicle__c)controller.getrecord();

            //this.AuditAutoPolicySample =  (Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c)controller.getRecord();  
            this.Audit = new Audit__c();
            this.IsNew = (this.AuditAutoVehicle.Id == null);


            //Get Audit Id Prefix
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Audit__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
            this.auditIdPrefix = dsr.getKeyPrefix();   

            //Get Audit Id & sample Id
            Id auditId = this.AuditAutoVehicle.Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__r.Audit__c;
            sampleID = AuditAutoVehicle.Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c;


            if (auditId == null) {
                string param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');               
                sampleID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sampleId');                

                if (isAuditId(param1)) {
                    auditId = param1;
                }
                else {              
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Invalid Audit Id. Please contact the help desk with this error'));
                }

            }

            //Load Audit Record
            List<Audit__c> audits = queryAudits(auditId);
            if (audits.isEmpty() == true) {

                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'No records were found. Please contact the help desk with this error'));                          

            }
            else if (audits.size() > 1) {

                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'More than 1 record found. Please contact the help desk with this error'));

            }
            else {
                this.Audit = audits[0];
                this.AuditAutoVehicle.Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c = sampleId;                
            }

            //Load Sample Record
            List<Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c> samples = querySamples(sampleID);
            if (samples.isEmpty() == true) {

                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'No sample records were found. Please contact the help desk with this error'));                          

            }
            else if (audits.size() > 1) {

                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'More than 1 sample record found. Please contact the help desk with this error'));

            }
            else {
                this.AuditAutoPolicySample = samples[0];                
            }

            //Load defaults from sample policy only for new Vehicles
            if (this.IsNew) {         

            this.AuditAutoVehicle.Liability__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_Liability_Limits__c;
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.PIP_Limits__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_PIP_Limits__c;
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.PIP_Deductible__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_PIP_Deductible__c;
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.UIM_Limits__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_UIM_Limits__c;
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.UM_Limits__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Default_UM_Limits__c;            
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_Liability_Limit__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_Liability_Limit__c;
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_PIP_Limit__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_PIP_Limit__c;
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_PIP_Deductible__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_PIP_Deductible__c;
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_UIM_Limit__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_UIM_Limit__c;
            this.AuditAutoVehicle.Other_UM_Limit__c = AuditAutoPolicySample.Other_UM_Limit__c;     
            }      

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
    }

    //Public Methods

    //return user back to the audit sample to add new record.
    public PageReference saveAndReturn()
    {
     stdController.save();  
     PageReference pr = Page.PROD_V2_Audit_Auto_PolicySample;
     pr.getParameters().put('id', sampleId);
     pr.setRedirect(true);
     return pr;
    }

    //Private Methods
    private boolean isAuditId(string value) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        if (value != null && value.length() >= 15 && value.length() <= 18) {
            isValid = value.startsWith(auditIdPrefix);
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    private List<Audit__c> queryAudits(Id auditId) {
        List<Audit__c> audits = new List<Audit__c>();
        if (auditId != null) {
            audits = [SELECT 
                        Id
                        , Name
                        , Policy_Information__c
                        , Policy_Number__c
                        , Prior_Carrier__c
                        , Expiring_Premium__c
                        , Reinstatement_Information__c
                        , Insured_Location__c
                        , Agent_Information__c
                        , Agent_City__c
                        , Agent_Name__c
                        , Driver_Information__c
                        , Age__c
                        , Gender__c
                        , Marital_Status__c
                        , Named_Insured_Add_Driver__c
                        , Occupation__c
                        , Business_Use__c
                        , Vehicle_Information__c
                        , Model_Year__c
                        , Vehicle_Type__c
                        , ISO_Symbol__c
                        , Annual_Miles__c
                        , Limit_Information__c
                        , Liability_Limits__c
                        , UM_Limits__c
                        , UIM_Limits__c
                        , UM_UIM_Limits__c
                        , PIP_Limits__c
                        , PIP_Deductible__c
                        , APD_Deductible_Vehicle__c
                        , Premium__c
                        , Rating_Information__c
                        , MVR_Violations__c
                        , Policy_Discounts__c
                        , Rating_Tier__c
                        , Credit_Scoring__c
                        , Telematics_UBI__c
                        , Loss_Information__c
                        , CLUE_Report__c
                        , Prior_Carrier_Loss_Experience__c
                        , Company_Loss_Experience__c
                        , Individual_Loss_Detail__c
                        , General_Information__c
                        , Signed_Application__c
                        , Vehicle_Photo_Information__c
                        , Proof_of_Ownership__c
                        , Other_Policies__c
                        , UW_Guidelines_Followed__c
                        , Risk_Management_Standards__c
                        , Personal_Auto_Product__c      
                FROM 
                    Audit__c 
                WHERE 
                    Id = :auditId];
        }

        return audits;
    }
        //query to retreive the policy default values for liability limit information for all new vehicles.
        private List<Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c> querySamples(Id sampleId) {
        List<Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c> samples = new List<Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c>();
        if (sampleId != null) {
            samples = [SELECT 
                        Id
                        , Name                        
                        , Default_Liability_Limits__c
                        , Default_PIP_Limits__c
                        , Default_PIP_Deductible__c
                        , Default_UIM_Limits__c
                        , Default_UM_Limits__c
                        , Other_Liability_Limit__c
                        , Other_PIP_Limit__c
                        , Other_PIP_Deductible__c
                        , Other_UIM_Limit__c
                        , Other_UM_Limit__c                            
                FROM 
                    Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c 
                WHERE 
                    Id = :sampleID];
        }

        return samples;
    }   
}
```

Unit Test Method:

@isTest static void testPageLoadNullID() {

```
//setup test environ     
Account acct = UtilityAudit.getAccount();
insert acct;
Audit__c audit = UtilityAudit.getAudit(acct.Id);
insert audit; 
Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c sample = UtilityAudit.getAuto_Audit_Sample_Policy(audit.Id);
insert sample;
//do not insert object. Pass instance in std controller (sc) This sets the auditId to null & forces controller to rely on grabbing the Id's simulated from the url.
//Auto_Vehicle__c vehicle = UtilityAudit.getAuto_Vehicle(sample.Id);     
//insert vehicle;

//create standard controller and extended controller instance
//pass empty instance of vehicle to simulate null ID for creating new page.
Auto_Vehicle__c vehicle = new Auto_Vehicle__c();
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(vehicle);

//initiate the VF page
PageReference pageRef = Page.PROD_V2_Audit_Auto_VehicleSample;
Test.setcurrentPage(pageref);
//Add parms to page URL - passed via custom button ?accId={!Audit__c.Id}&sampleId={!Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c.Id}
Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('AccId', audit.Id);
Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('sampleID', sample.Id);

//Start Test
Test.startTest();

AuditAutoVehicleSampleController testVehiclePage = new AuditAutoVehicleSampleController(sc);

Test.stopTest();

//Verify page status
System.assertEquals(false, ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.Error), 'Expected no errors to be reported for using IDs from new page creation');

}  // END TEST testPageLoadNullID
```

Comment: You are not getting coverage because your condition of `if (this.IsNew)` is false. You are creating the `ApexPage.standardController(vehicle)` with an object that has been inserted into the database. As such, `vehicle` will have an `Id`. Therefore, these two lines will always result in `isNew == false`:
    `this.AuditAutoVehicle = (Auto_Vehicle__c)controller.getrecord();
    this.IsNew = (this.AuditAutoVehicle.Id == null);`

Comment: I recommend you add more debug statements to find out why your data isn't being populated or making beyond the correct if-else statements. You don't state that your test is failing, so I can only assume that your data isn't making it past your if statements since in a number of places I don't see else statements that would trigger a flag to let you know where the problem lays.

Comment: This was resolved by adding another method forcing the controller to read from the id's passed via URL reference (simulating a new record creation.) Updated the unit test above by not inserting the Vehicle object and passing an empty instance of vehicle to the standard controller extension. This causes the ID's to be null allowing the code to branch to these untested lines.

Comment: rickmac or andrew -- post as solution please

Comment: the solution is reflected in the updated unit test above. There I've commented out the object 'not' to insert and created an empty instance before loading the controller. (for ex: //do not insert object. Pass instance in std controller (sc) This sets the auditId to null & forces  ....)